# How can I get LaTeX working on Anki?

Tags: install, latex

Originally I was going to ask a question about how to get [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) working in [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/), but as I was writing the question, I was trying to solve the problem myself. I thought others may benefit from my findings, so I decided to post them here. If you notice that any of my steps are wrong, please let me know. And I was still unable to get it to work, so if you scroll down to the end, you can see where I'm stuck and still need help.

The current issue is: **How can I install libgd?**

---

I'm trying to make [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) work with [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/). The only information I could find about how to do this is from [this page](http://ankisrs.net/docs/AddItems.html#_advanced_latex):

> - [...] to use LaTeX, you have to install it separately - it is not  bundled with Anki
> - [...] on OSX use MacTex
> - Dvipng must also be installed.
> - On OSX, if you use MacPorts or similar to install LaTeX, make sure latex and dvipng are linked in /usr/bin.

The standard installation of [MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/) takes up 3GB, far more than I believe is necessary, since I am not going to use its GUI application. I just need the LaTeX library, if I understand it correctly, which should be way less than 3GB. Therefore, I'm installing the [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) version instead, which only takes up about 100MB.

I'm not sure if I already have [Dvipng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvipng/) installed or not, so I'm restarting Anki to see if it works or not. I got the following error:

> Error executing dvipng. [...] Output written on tmp.dvi [...]

So I probably need to install dvipng... The Install readme has the following information:

> Installing dvipng should be simple: merely `./configure',`make', and
>   `make install'.
>
> Prerequisites:
>
> - The GD Graphics Draw library, libgd
> - The path-searching library kpathsea
> - libpng and libz

Again, I'm not sure which, if any, of these prerequisites I already have installed, so I'm just going ahead with the installation in hopes of error messages guiding me to the right path.

After executing `./config`, it gives the error:

> configure: error: cannot find/use libpng

... which I think is weird since the readme states:

> ```
>  To be able to compress and write PNG files to disk, dvipng (or
>  really libgd) uses libpng which in turn uses libz. These should be
>  available on any modern system, if not, download them and install
>  them.
> ```

I went to the [libpng website](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), and tried finding a "current binary" that works with my OS (10.6/i386), but it seems that none of the latest 3 versions have a binary that is available to download. So I went to the "old binaries" section, which took me to [this website](http://ethan.tira-thompson.org/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html), which has libpng v1.4.5. I installed the "Individual Installer package" for libpng.

Now that it's installed, I tried installing Dvipng again, and it now gives the following error:

> cannot find/use libgd
>   This drawing library can be downloaded at http://www.boutell.com/gd

When I go to [that website](http://www.boutell.com/gd/), I see it says that the page moved and that it is currently down. There is only a link to the source files and no binary distribution. I'm not sure where I should go from here... should I download the source and compile it somehow? Once it's complied what do I do with it? Do I run some file it generates? Would I move files it generates to specific folders? How would Dvipng know how to access it? I'm unfamiliar with how to do something like this, so any help would be appreciated.

---

Here's a summary (so far) of the dependency hierarchy which must be installed in order to get LaTeX to work with Anki:

- [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html): Installed (got the BasicTeX version to save a lot of disk space).
- [Dvipng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvipng/): Not installed (can't install without libgd).

  - [libpng](http://ethan.tira-thompson.org/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html): Installed (got the Individual Installer package).
  - libgd: Not installed (not sure how to install this).
  - ???

---

Other questions:

- Is there a better, reliable method to know if any of these dependencies are installed rather than running an installer which depends on them and hoping for a meaningful error message?

Answer (score 17):

Your question was very helpful to me in getting LaTeX working with Anki, but I've found there's an easier way to get dvipng:

1. Install MacTeX.  I installed BasicTeX-2011.pkg (MacTeX-Additions-2011.mpkg is NOT required).
2. Open the terminal, type "tlmgr update --self && tlmgr install dvipng" and press enter. It will update TeX Live Manager and install the latest dvipng.

Once you do that, you should be all set.

Comment: I agree. It is much better to install packages in MacTex via Tex Live Utility than the command line. This suggestion should work.

Comment: Question: I am the only admin on my system but when I try and run the terminal command "tlmgr update --self && tlmgr install dvipng" I get an error saying I need to run the program as an admin. I am the admin! How do I run this program? I need it to properly configure latex on OSX10.6 (Snow Leopard) because I am having pdflatex/ dvipng errors after a new install of BasicTex. Thanks!

Comment: For posterity: the answer to @user21373's question is to use the 'sudo' command.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this exact problem but the command "tlmgr update --self && tlmgr install dvipng" did not work and I got the error I need to run the program as an admin.

The user account I was using was an admin account.
What I did instead is run each command separately as sudo:
At the Mac OS X Terminal prompt:

```
$ sudo tlmgr update --self
```

(wait for this command to grab updates and compete)

```
$ sudo tlmgr install dvipng
```

This worked and installed tlmgr updates as well as dvipng, causing Anki to display LaTeX output!

Comment: You can run these commands as a one-liner with `sudo tlmgr update --self && sudo tlmgr install dvipng`

Answer (score 3):

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, the easiest way is:

```
brew install basictex && sudo tlmgr update --self && sudo tlmgr install dvipng
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I think it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is also documented on https://docs.ankiweb.net/math.html#assumed-knowledge.

Comment: Note 1: You might have to restart the terminal/open a new terminal after installing basictex and then run both `tlmgr` commands.

Note 2: Latex math env in Anki i.e. [latex]$$\frac{1}{2}$$[/latex] need the $$ signs inside of it.