# Issues with Anki and BasicTeX

Tags: macos, command-line, install, latex

My last Mac worked with Anki to display LaTeX formatted equations but I am still, but I haven't been able to transfer it over.

My steps thus far:

1. I obviously downloaded and installed Anki and BasicTeX (don't want the size of MacTeX).
2. I use an equation in my cards with proper formatting and get the error others have reported on:

`Error executing dvipng.
Generated file: /var/folders/x2/8dh4jx2j64n9tvvts_l2pqk00000gp/T/anki_temp/tmp.tex`

3. My understanding is that dvipng comes bundled with BasicTex so this is pretty perplexing.
4. I tried the extension https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/937148547 but it is not working. When I type `which latex` (and a million other variants), it cannot be found.
5. I tried following the advice from the top answer here: [How can I get LaTeX working on Anki?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/how-can-i-get-latex-working-on-anki]]), but when I use `tlmgr update --self && tlmgr install dvipng`, I get that the tlmgr command is not found (same thing when I sudo it.)

Other information: I am running all of this on a MacBook Pro with El Capitan installed.

Comment: The default location for BasicTex's latex command is `/Library/TeX/texbin/latex`. Would you mind adding the output of both `which latex`, `stat /Library/TeX/texbin/latex` and `ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2015basic` (substitute the year of your installation if applicable)? Also, your `echo $PATH` would be helpful.