# Latex not working on Anki, even though I have mactex installed

Tags: latex

For example, I've tried typing on the front of an anki card,

Does [latex]\begin{math}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\end{math}[/latex] converge?

given in the example on the official anki website. However it doesn't translate it into its latex equivalent. I've already tried following the instructions in this thread,

[How can I get LaTeX working on Anki?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/how-can-i-get-latex-working-on-anki)

which actually shouldn't apply to me, since I already have MacTex installed and not BasicTex.

Comment: Have you tried https://tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be better in the tex site

Comment: It’s certainly allowed here. If the OP wants it moved, we can move it of course.